# How can I efficiently work with arrays from php while loop?

Tags: php, json

I have a table of columns; a, b, c in php Sqlite3 and I want to construct an array consisting of those columns.
After fetching the column names in php Sqlite3 and encoding the results to Json, am getting the output of the following format;

```
["a"]["a","b"]["a","b","c"]
```

My idea is to construct an array of this form `["a","b","c"]` or perhaps get contents of the last square bracket in the above output.
Is there any step I am missing or how should I get my required output?
Below is my php code;

```
<?php
// Database name
$database_name = "my_sqlite.db";

// Database Connection
$db = new SQLite3($database_name);

// Create Table "students" into Database if not exists
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students (a STRING, b STRING, c STRING)";
$db->exec($query);
?>
<?php
$tablesquery = $db->query("PRAGMA table_info(students);"); 
while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) { 
    //$r[] = $table['Field'];
    $ary[] = $table["name"];
    $colns = json_encode($ary);
    echo $colns;               

    //this gives ["a"]["a","b"]["a","b","c"]
    //my desired output ["a","b","c"];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop, you add one row name at a time into the $ary array.  And you print the array in each iteration of the while loop, so it makes sense you see that output.

What you should do is loop to add names into the array, but only print it once, after the while is completed.

Like this:

```
while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) { 
    //$r[] = $table['Field'];
    $ary[] = $table["name"];
}

$colns = json_encode($ary);
echo $colns;
```

Performing the `echo` inside the loop showed you the array being built, not just the final content, like the code above does.

Comment: Indeed. I qppreciate your help sir. @Nic3500